# Oracle pipelined function with generic record type?

Tags: oracle, collections, pipelined-function

I have a pipelined function which returns results of a SQL query:

```
function my_pipelined_function(...)
    return rec_t
    PIPELINED is
  begin
    for l in (select * from ... join ... where ...) loop
       PIPE ROW(l);
    end loop;
  
    return;
  end;
```

This works, but I have to define the record and it's type in the package header:

```
 TYPE rec IS RECORD(
   some_date_param date,
   some_number_param number,
   ...
 );

 TYPE rec_t IS TABLE OF rec;
```

Ugly. Isn't there a way to avoid having to declare the "hard-coded" record with all types defined, one by one?

I saw the [`ANYDATA`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_anydat.htm#ARPLS077) type, but I can't make it work. Should I use this approach, if yes, how to do it? If not, should I use some kind of ref cursor, or is this simply not possible at all in Oracle?

Thanks

Comment: You may return `sys_refcursor` instead of pipe and fetch it on the client side. Anyway, as far as I know, you cannot declare generic type and get sensible access to its content (like consume in SQL). At least because parser should know if column exists in the result set.

Comment: Mayby you are looking for a `SQL Macro`. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66590887/4808122) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66732311/4808122)